# What is the right way of passing an object to a template constructor or method

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have a Shop template class and a Cookie class and trying to create a dynamic array of Cookie kind (or something else's kind since it is a template) and add more if required as follows in my main function such as:

```
template <typename shopType>
class Shop {
private:
    int noi;                 // number of items
    double totalcost;   
    shopType * sTptr;        // for dynamic array
public:
    Shop(shopType &);
    void add(shopType &);
    .....
```

and

```
int main() {
.....
    Cookie cookie1("Chocolate Chip Cookies", 10, 180);  
    Cookie cookie2("Cake Mix Cookies", 16, 210);

    Shop<Cookie> cookieShop(cookie1);       // getting error here
    cookieShop.add(cookie2);                // and here
.....
```

with constructor and methods I wrote like:

```
template<typename shopType>
Shop<shopType>::Shop(shopType & sT)
{
    sTptr = new shopType;
    sTptr = sT;                           // not allowed, how can I fix ?
    noi = 1;
    totalcost = sT.getCost();
}

template<typename shopType>
void Shop<shopType>::add(shopType & toAdd)
{
    if (noi == 0) {
        sTptr = new shopType;
        sTptr = toAdd;                   // not allowed, how can I fix ?
        totalcost = toAdd.getCost();
        noi++;
    }
    else {
        shopType * ptr = new shopType[noi + 1];
        for (int a = 0; a < noi; a++) {
            ptr[a] = sTptr[a];
        }

        delete[] sTptr;

        sTptr = ptr;
        sTptr[noi++] = toAdd;
        totalcost += toAdd.getCost();
    }
}
```

and I am naturally getting **C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'Cookie' to 'Cookie *'**  error...

I understand what I am doing wrong but I can't figure it out how to do it in the right way...

Should creating a new Cookie pointer and copying the one in parameter to it would work, or something else? Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to copy the passed parameter to the member variable? If so Dereferencing pointer first before assignment would be sufficient: `*sTptr = toAdd`. Or even better: `sTptr = new shopType (toAdd)`. Since your intentions isn't clear, I didn't post this as an answer. In addition, consider avoiding manual memory management in C++, since it is error-prone. Consider using `std::unique_ptr` for pointers, and `std::vector` for variable sized arrays instead. Also, deleting with `delete[]` something that was allocated with `new` (instead of `new[]`) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius  Since this is part of an learning assignment I am not allowed to use STL... sTptr is meant to point to a dynamic array of cookies at the end, that why I am using delete [] ... Actually I don't want to copy the passed parameter but trying to make it the very first element of my dynamic array which is pointed by sTptr   so that I can  add  more  later  with  my add function

Comment: `new shopType;` is not an array allocation. And deallocating it with `delete[]` is undefined behavior. On the second look, if your array already contains elements you copy it over with `sTptr[noi++] = toAdd;`, but now you are saying you don't want to copy it in a first-element case.. I am confused.

Comment: Believe me, I am more confused than you  :)   Thanks for your time and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message from the compiler is pretty clear. You are trying to assign a `shopType` to a `shopType*` in the line:

```
sTptr = toAdd;
```

Unless you have very strong reasons for managing memory for the array yourself, use a `std::vector` to store the objects in a `Shop`.

```
template <typename shopType>
class Shop {
   private:
      // There is no need for this.
      // int noi;                 // number of items
      double totalcost;   
      std::vector<shopType> shopItems;

      // ...
};
```

Then, `Shop::add` can be implemented simply as (I changed the argument type to a `const` reference):

```
template<typename shopType>
void Shop<shopType>::add(shopType const& toAdd)
{
   shopItems.push_back(toAdd);
}
```

Comment: STL is really a time saver but my intend was there to implement it without using STL. Anyways, I have switched to vector and implemented it as in the example above.